# Enter string repeatedly Ruby Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have a test that includes character lengths within fields etc.

I was wondering if I could have a set string of 10 characters like `str = 'abcdefghij'`
then have it multiply that string by the amount of times needed to fulfil the character length and fill in the field.

I've tried the `times` method but that just enters the same value over x iterations.

What I want is to take str, increase it ten fold and enter that value as 1 continuous string so `abcdefghij` becomes `abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij` etc

I'd parameterize the number of times to increase it depending on the field I'm testing. I want to do this so that I don't have huge amounts of variables stored to satisfy each test.

Can this be done? I hope I've explained clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String#*`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-2A) would do:

```
'abc' * 10
#⇒ "abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc"
```

To use a floating point parameter:

```
λ = ->(input, count) do
  i, f = *count.divmod(1)
  input * i << input[0...(f * input.size).to_i]
end

λ.('abcd', 2.5)
#⇒ 'abcdabcdab'
```

Comment: When I tried originally it didn't work, just tried again and it did. Man, thanks!